# Check for selected items in a ListBox bound to an ObservableCollection in a MVVM application

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, listbox

Given the two Model in my MVVM application:

**MyFolder** that contains a list of Files (**MyFiles**):

```
public class MyFolder
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public List<MyFile> FilesList { get; set; }
}

public class MyFile
{
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
}
```

In my Viewmodel I have an ObservableCollection with folders:

```
    public ObservableCollection<MyFolder> FoldersList { get; set; }
```

I am viewing the folders in a ListBox and in another ListBox I show the list of files of the selected folder (defined also in the ViewModel):

private MyFolder selectedFolder;

```
    public MyFolder SelectedFolder
    {
        get { return selectedFolder; }
        set
        {
            selectedFolder = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedFolder));
        }
    }
```

What I need is to be able to select some of the files shown in the ListBox to perform some action on them (lets say changing their extensions)

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FoldersList.FilesList}"  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedFolder, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ????}"/>
                <Label VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="{Binding Path=Path}">
             </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

I can add a property to MyFiles Class like bool Selected and then bind this property to the CheckBox.

But, is this the way to do it in MVVM pattern?

Or how should I go about it?

Any idea is really appreciated.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Nearly.  Your ViewModel class is simply a mapping of behaviour between view and model, and you don't seem to have such a layer.  The classes that you show here are clearly model classes, but you should have a viewmodel class between the two.  That class would then maintain values such as whether the item is selected in the view.

Comment: @LordWilmore i'm pretty sure that OP posted only the relevant code. He already have a viewmodel in which he store the FoldersList, so i suppose i have the logic there too.

Comment: @DanieleSartori The OP was asking about the correct MVVM approach.  The classes MyFile and MyFolder look like Model classes to me.  If they're not, and they are actually ViewModel classes, then we're both right ;)

Comment: @LordWilmore: thank you for your reply, yes i do have a VM that has a FolderList... But you mean i still need a FolderViewModel (wrappers over my models) like in the answer below? the VM in my case has only the list of folders that i fill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend having 2 view models namely

`FolderViewModel` and `FileViewModel`, they both are essentially wrappers over your model class but can have UI Related functionality as well.

so your fileViewModel will have a property called say `IsSelected` or any more that you need, your `FolderViewModel` will have a collection of `FileViewModel`. you can fire your property changes from fileViewModel itself and there by making it more extensible and stronger MVVM

```
public class Folder
{
    //Model PROPERTIES
    IEnumerable<File> Files { get; set; }
}

public class File
{
    //Model PROPERTIES
}

public class FolderViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //View Model PROPERTIES
    IEnumerable<FileViewModel> Files { get; set; }
}

public class FileViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //View Model PROPERTIES
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. Does this means i am keeping the "buisness logic" out of the Model? for me, this is how i would do it, but it is a lot of efort. But in the other hand having a property like isSelected does not belong in the file class

Comment: consider model as a repository, No Business logic should go in model. Model can be share between multiple viewmodels, consider a case where you have same model displayed on two views, you select on one and not select on another...... but having isSelected in one model will affect your model in both the views..... a stitch in time saves nine

Comment: also consider a case where you need to mark renames files as highlighted, where would you put that logic into ? FileModel ?? NO!

Answer (score 2):

The approach you have described seems legit to me, However note that you have to implement INotifyPropertyChanged also in your MyFile class, or your binding to the checkbox won't work.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Path=FoldersList.FilesList}"  SelectedItem="{Binding Path=SelectedFolder, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <StackPanel>
             <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Checked}"/>
             <Label VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Content="{Binding Path=Path}">
          </StackPanel>
       </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>



public class MyFile : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public void SetPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public string Path { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    private bool _checked = false;
    public bool Checked
    {
        get {return _checked;}
        set
            {
               _checked = value;
               SetPropertyChanged("Checked");
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you.. i already have the Interface implemented but skipped it for easy reading of the question

Comment: that is how i would do it. Until you don't break MVVM pattern by messing with your view and viewmodel, it's ok. The approach you choose is pretty standard (usually i do the same in situation like yours)

Comment: @lebhero do you really want that checkbox? if not you could restyle the ItemContainerTemplate to bind the IsSelected from ListBoxItem to your model bool property. then you dont need the checkbox, because listbox provides selection mechanism anyways

Comment: @Milan While that is true, i think that a checkbox is far more "user friendly.", in terms of clarity of the application

Comment: thank you both for the suggestion. The CheckBox is indeed a requirment..